# Set list items in ng-model in a dropdownmenu angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

currently I stuck with an angularjs problem. The following scenario:

I have a Game entity and a Team entity. One Game can hold multiple Team objects. (ManyToMany Relationship)

In my frontend application I want to add a new Game with optional Teams. For the Teams I decided to use two dropdown-menus (each menu for one team).

Now I am not able to give the ng-model the correct values.

I tried something like this but it might be wrong:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="team.teamname for team in teams 
track by team.id" ng-model="game.teams[0]">
  <option value="" selected>-- No Team --</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" ng-options="team.teamname for team in teams 
track by team.id" ng-model="game.teams[1]">
  <option value="" selected>-- No Team --</option>
</select>
```

As soon as I click the save button i get an error message "400: Unable to process JSON":

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to process JSON"},"status":400,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","data":{"teams":{"0":{"id":1,"games":[{"id":1,"date":20180810}],"teamname":"BVB"},"1":{"id":2,"games":[{"id":1,"date":20180810}],"teamname":"FCB"}},"date":"20180810"},"url":"/api/games","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

When creating the two Teams for a Game with Postman it works:

```
{
    "date": 20180810,
    "teams": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "date": 20180810,
  "teams": [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "games": [
              {
                  "id": 1,
                  "date": 20180810
              }
          ],
          "teamname": "BVB"
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "games": [
              {
                  "id": 1,
                  "date": 20180810
              }
          ],
          "teamname": "FCB"
      }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions how to set the ng-model (Game) with the values of the first and second dropdown-menus? thanks

I have added a screenshot of the form that i want to have:
[image]

Comment: It would be more helpful, if you prepared a working demo snippet or a fiddle instead of just showing codes and showing screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand well, when you do the request with postman, you send this:

```
{
    "date": 20180810,
    "teams": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]
}
```

But your angular form is actually sending this:

```
{
    "date": "20180810"
    "teams": {
        "0": {
            "id": 1,
            "games": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "date": 20180810
                }
            ],
            "teamname": "BVB"
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 2,
            "games": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "date": 20180810
                }
            ],
            "teamname": "FCB"
        }
    }
}
```

While the `date` looks fine, your `teams` is an object but your backend is expecting an array. You also have additional informations in your teams (like `games` and `teamname`, but i can't know if this is a problem for your backend.

Most of the time this kind of problems with Angularjs are not in the html template but in the controller. In your controller you should have something like this:

```
scope.game = {
    date: 'something',
    teams: []
};
```

I think your problem is that you don't initialize `scope.game.teams` as an array properly. So `ng-model` just initliaze it by itself with an object.

Comment: Indeed I forgot to initialize the scope.game.teams. The problem was solved by adding $scope.game.teams = []; in my controller. thx. [https://jsfiddle.net/uumksbvd/](https://jsfiddle.net/uumksbvd/) Here is a fiddle example of the topics issue. I used a service to share the values.

Comment: Now I face another problem: When i refresh the page multiple times, the order of the teams in the table switches. refresh -> [teamid:1, teamid:2], refresh -> [teamid:2, teamid:1]. How can I make this positions fix?

Answer (score 0):

From what i gather you want to add multiple teams for each game, follow the checklist model, its probably what you want, https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/ from there you can pass the server a list of games for each team

Comment: I would prefer a dropdownmenu if this is possible. I think the mistake that i made is the wrong expression to save the teams into the model. But I have no clue how to write it in angularjs.. I added a screenshot to demonstrate how it should look like.

Comment: you can use the checklist model in a dropdown, its possible to nest it and then style it accordingly to hide the box and change it to highlight each selected one